# A question about relative homology group

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I want to find two space pairs $(X,A)$ and $(Y,B)$ such that $X$ is homotopic to $Y$ and $A$ is homotopic to $B$, but their relative homology group is not isomorphic, that is
$$
H_*(X,A)\neq H_*(Y,B)
$$

Comment: Please provide some context (why do you care) and show the work you have done to solve this problem…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** use reduced homology ie. take $A=\{x_1\}$, $B=\{x_2\}$ in distinct connected components of a space space $X=Y$, such that the two connected components $C_1, C_2$ have different homologies.